# Stripe payment for a visitor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, stripe-payments

In my Rails app, I need to create a Stripe payment on the homepage so that visitors would be able to pay just by writing an email address above the call-to-action pay button. There is no user registration, anyone should be able to pay without registering on the website and get some update at the email address they entered when they paid.

I thought about saving the visitor's email address in a users table in database but then I cannot figure out how to create the instance of the user model "on the fly" without a real devise-like registration form. Once again, there is no official sign up possibility on this app, just email address and payment button to show Stripe popup.

Any clue to solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to grab the email from the email input field using js and make an ajax call to a controller action you'll set up for this purpose. Inside the controller action you'll just create a user in your user model `User.create(email: params[:email])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find everything you need in the [Rails Checkout Guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails).